# Executing multiple commands on command line linux

Tags: linux, macos, shell, command

I want to run multiple commands on command line in linux.  Here's the example:

abc.txt:
hello

```
$ test 'cat abc.txt'
```

Here test is a command which runs agains the value of abc.txt and abc.txt is the file which have some value.

How can i print the value from the file and run the test command ?

Comment: Beware of using "test" as the name of your command.  It is already a command and, depending on your PATH, it may be executed before your local "test", thus rendering unexpected results.  Run this command to see which "test" your shell will actually run: "which test".  To run your local "test", you may need to proceed it with a dot-slash, to force the shell to look in the current directory first: "./test "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs `cat abc.txt`, placing the contents of that file the command line where they are used as arguments to the command `test`:

```
test "$(cat abc.txt)"
```